# Search file in IProject - Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to find a specific file present in eclipse project which is in classpath of project.

I have `IProject` instance but Dont know how to get `IFile` instance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IProject` interface extends the `IContainer` which has several `findMember` methods. You get an IResource which can be casted down to `IFile` after checking its' type  using `getType`. Go over those interfaces, they are properly documented.

Comment: findMembers didnt worked for me....
But I tried Icontainer.members() and it worked..
Thanks for help...

Comment: I have several years of experience in Eclipse plugin development. If there's one advice I can give you it is: use the source. Develop your code browsing and reading skills and make sure the sources I always readily available.

Comment: Beware that the `IProject` doesn't care for the classpath.
And the `members()` function will return only direct child objects.

So what you got was not a file in the classpath, but directly in the project root directory.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and this is in short what i did:

```
IResource getResource(IProject project, String folderPath, String fileName) {

    IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);
    for (IPackageFragmentRoot root : javaProject.getAllPackageFragmentRoots()) {
        IPackageFragment folderFragment = root.getPackageFragement(folderPath);
        IResource folder = folderFragment.getResource();
        if (folder == null || ! folder.exists() || !(folder instanceof IContainer)) {
            continue;
        }

        IResource resource = ((IContainer) folder).findMember(fileName);
        if (resource.exists()) {
            return resource;
        }
    }

    // file not found in any source path
    return null;
}
```

It looks pretty ugly and maybe there's a more direct approach. But it works.

If you need to use the classpath, you have to use `IJavaProject` and the way fragments work prevents directly searching for the file path, because it will assume the "." (period) in a file name is a java package separator. So i guess you have to first get the right folder and then the file.

Comment: This works only with java projects! If you have pde(plugin) or other projects JavaCore.create(project) creates an not existing project.